# Get URL for Salesforce Lead (Python Beatbox SOAP API)

Tags: python, soap, salesforce, beatbox

I'm using Beatbox to access Salesforce's SOAP API. I can query for a series of Leads—

```
SELECT Id FROM Lead
```

Does anyone know how I can create a URL to view each Lead on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out the URL of your instance (naX.salesforce.com) and generate a link pointing to:

```
http://naX.salesforce.com/<leadId>
```

If the user is not logged in it will ask for credentials and redirect him after the login is completed.

Comment: Thank you geekymartian! Asking internally, that looks to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL of your Salesforce instance from Beatbox. Assuming you started out connecting with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import beatbox
svc = beatbox.Client()
```

Get the URL here:

```
svc._Client__serverUrl
```

Format it a bit:

```
print('{}://{}/'.format(
    urlparse(svc._Client__serverUrl).scheme,
    urlparse(svc._Client__serverUrl).netloc)
)
```

Sample output:

```
https://na59.salesforce.com/
```